# Is client_body_buffer_size per-connection?

Tags: nginx

I'm not able to tell from reading [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_buffer_size) whether `client_body_buffer_size` means per-connection or per-server (or does it depend on where the directive is set?)

I would like to create a large in-memory buffer (16m) to allow occasional large uploads to be speedy. But I want that to be a *shared* 16m -- if there are a lot of concurrent uploads then slowing down to disk-speed is fine.